Multiple custom variables in Jmeter dashboard
According to this thread Custom info in Jmeter dashboard.
My current requirement is to use the two variables in the result I get from sending the http request as the X and Y axes of the report. But I don't know how to set it.
I extract the two required variable values ​​from the returned result of each HTTP request, Product Code and Duration_Time：

The output of these two variables to CSV looks like this:

But, Now I want to using those two variables as the X and Y axes to generate the dashboard.
I have change the user.properties like below:
sample_variables=PRODUCT_CODE,Duration_Time
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.classname=org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.CustomGraphConsumer
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.title=The Duration Time Report For XXXX
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_Y_Axis=PRODUCT_CODE
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.set_X_Axis=Duration_Time
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_granularity=60000
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_Sample_Variable_Name=Duration_Time
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_Content_Message=Duration_Time:

The dashboard is:

Apparently：

PRODUCT_CODE as Y coordinate, its value is incorrect, it should be 1024, 1025.
Duration_Time as the X coordinate, its value is also incorrect and is not displayed.
It should form a wavy curve, like below, but now it only shows the last value.



As of JMeter 5.6 it's not possible out of the box, if you look into official documentation:

You can graph any sample_variable in CSV over time, you can customize your graphs by settings their properties in the user.properties file.

So you can plot a sample variable value over time, you cannot use other variable as X axis. You can change report template according to your needs but it assumes amending Freemarker definitions
